# How to place header on top of container in thesis theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am having problem with the placing of header part above my container part using thesis theme for wordpress as i am unable to do so.

```
<body class=" customize-support">
<div id="logo"> </div>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1 id="site_title">
<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>
</h1>
<p id="site_tagline"></p>
</div>
<ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu">
<div class="columns">
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

Comment: You have to provide more details ? What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: i am having header inside my container and what i want to do is to simply move the header outside of my conatiner part.. thats it

Comment: i am having this hierarchy    1.logo 2.container 3.header   and i have to move header to the 2nd position and rest remains same

Comment: You should post your template code that has the html wrappers.

Comment: <div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1 id="site_title">
<a href="http://example.com">Header</a>
</h1>
<p id="site_tagline"></p>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by adjusting css according to your need.